# How to connect to Vault Hashicorp with PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, hashicorp-vault, powercli

I am very new to Vault and PowerShell, i need to connect to Vault and grab a secret key using PowerShell.

This is my code

```
$Vault_Address       = 'xxx'
$VAULT_ROOT          = $Vault_Address + '/v1'
$VAULT_LOGIN_APPROLE = $VAULT_ROOT+'/auth/approle/login'
$VAULT_KV_PATH       = $VAULT_ROOT+'/xx/xx/xx'

$RoleID              = 'default'
$SecretID            = 'default'

#Set env variable for vault address
$ENV:VAULT_ADDR = $Vault_Address

function Get-Vault
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    Param
    (
        # Server Address
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [String]
        $Address = $env:VAULT_ADDR,

        # Client token
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [String]
        $Token = $env:VAULT_TOKEN
    )


    [PSCustomObject]@{'uri'= $Address + $prefix
                      'auth_header' = @{'X-Vault-Token'=$Token}
                      } |
    Write-Output

}
```

It returns this error message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylfEG.png)

Comment: Does it need some sort of cert?  --cacert vault-ca.pem

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you what worked for me, hopefully it would help you or someone else.

Assuming on the UI you connect to `https://vault.domain/ui/vault/secrets?namespace=myVaultNamespace` and you have a secret engine `kvSecretEngine` which contains key-value secrets with the path of `PROD`:

```
$namespace = "myVaultNamespace"
$mountpoint = "kvSecretEngine"
$vaultpath = "PROD"

$headers = @{
    'Accept' = 'application/json'
    'X-Vault-Namespace' = $namespace
    'X-Vault-Token' = $vault_token
    }
$uri = "https://vault.domain/v1/$mountpoint/$vaultpath"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri $uri

$secret = $response.data
```

`$secret` will contain a JSON with all the secret key-values.
Hope it helps.